# Type checking errors in @react-navigation/native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, typescript-typings

I am working on a React-native application and it have nested routes (stack and bottom-tabs), but typescript is giving some errors while providing the types, I have gone the [official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#nesting-navigators)  also many posts on this platform but didn't found any answer, below I have given types I a using for different navigation groups

```js
export type RootBottomTabsParamList = {
  Dashboard: undefined;
  Categories: CategoriesStackParamList | undefined;
  Favorites: undefined;
  Cart: undefined;
  Settings: undefined;
};

export type BottomTabsNavigationProps = BottomTabNavigationProp<
  RootBottomTabsParamList,
  'Categories'
>;

export type CategoriesStackParamList = {
  CategoriesMain: undefined;
  Niche: {category: string; name: string} | undefined;
};

export type CategoriesScreenNavigationProps = StackNavigationProp<
  CategoriesStackParamList,
  'Niche'
>;

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Login: undefined;
  SignUp: undefined;
  Home: RootBottomTabsParamList | undefined;
  Product:
    | {img: string; name: string; price: string; description: sting}
    | undefined;
};

export type RootNavigationProps = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>;
```

and this are the routes where I am using it

```js
import React from 'react';
import {BackHandler, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
//screens
import {
  Cart,
  Categories,
  Dashboard,
  Favorites,
  Login,
  Product,
  Settings,
  SignUp,
  Niche,
} from './screens';
import {
  createNavigationContainerRef,
  DefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {useAppDispatch, useAppSelector} from './redux/hook';
import {AppDispatch, RootState} from './redux/store';
import {setCart, setFavorites, setUser} from './redux/actions';
import {IProduct} from './utils/interfaces/common';
import {
  CategoriesStackParamList,
  RootBottomTabsParamList,
  RootNavigationProps,
  RootStackParamList,
} from './utils/interfaces/navigation';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();

export function navigate(name: string, params?: {}) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name as never, params as never);
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<
  RootStackParamList | CategoriesStackParamList
>();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootBottomTabsParamList>();

const StackCategories = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="CategoriesMain" component={Categories} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Niche" component={Niche} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const bottomTabRoutes = [
  {name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard, iconName: 'home'},
  {name: 'Categories', component: StackCategories, iconName: 'apps'},
  {name: 'Favorites', component: Favorites, iconName: 'favorite'},
  {name: 'Cart', component: Cart, iconName: 'shopping-cart'},
  {name: 'Settings', component: Settings, iconName: 'settings'},
];

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        headerTitleStyle: {fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '600'},
        lazy: true,
      }}>
      {bottomTabRoutes.map(screen => (
        <Tab.Screen
          key={screen.name}
          name={screen.name}
          component={screen.component}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: props => (
              <Icon {...props} name={screen.iconName} size={15} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default function Routes() {
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const userId = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.ui.user?.uid);
  const isDarkTheme = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.ui.dark);
  const backBtnClicked = React.useRef(0);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    async function check() {
      auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    }
    check();
  }, []);
 

  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      theme={isDarkTheme ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={Product} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**Issues(refer the above code for the images below) :**

[image]

- In the above image you can see in navigate function there is a ts error : `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`, you can the same issues in images below too

[image]

[image]

- When using `useNavigation` hook, I am getting the error `Property 'navigate' does not exist on type 'StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, keyof RootStackParamList, undefined>'.`

```js
  const navigation = useNavigation<StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>>();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you!!

Your Code

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList | CategoriesStackParamList
>();

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootBottomTabsParamList>();
```

change like this

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I already tried it and it's doesn't work